# Controller methods called twice?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

base controller:

```
public class AnaController : Controller
{
    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        ViewBag.AktifKullanici = kullaniciServis.AktifKullanici(KullaniciEposta);
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

controller that is inherited from above controller:

```
public class AnasayfaController : AnaController
{
    private HaberSitesiDbContext db;
    private HaberServis haberServis;
    private KullaniciServis kullaniciServis;

    public AnasayfaController()
    {
        this.db = new HaberSitesiDbContext();
        this.haberServis = new HaberServis(db);
        this.kullaniciServis = new KullaniciServis(db);
    }

    // !!! following methods called twice !!!

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult _SolManset()
    {
        // id si 2 olanlar sol manset haberleri
        var haberler = haberServis.PozisyonHaberler(2, 3)
            .ToList();

        return PartialView(haberler);
    }

    public ActionResult _Slider()
    {
        // id si 1 olanlar slider haberleri
        var haberler = haberServis.PozisyonHaberler(1, 19)
            .ToList();

        return PartialView(haberler);
    }

    public ActionResult _Yazarlar()
    {
        var yazarlar = haberServis.KoseYazilari(5)
            .ToList();

        return PartialView(yazarlar);
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        db.Dispose();
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

layout:

```
...
<article id="body">
    @RenderBody()
</article>
...
```

Index:

```
<aside class="aside_small float_left">
   @Html.Action("_SolManset", "Anasayfa")
</aside>
<section class="section_middle">
   @Html.Action("_Slider", "Anasayfa")
</section>
<aside class="aside_small float_right">
   @Html.Action("_Yazarlar", "Anasayfa")
</aside>
```

I cant find any solution. Any suggestion? There is no extra code, no js code. How can I find where second calling come from?

Comment: The index method is called twice?

Comment: Have you tried stepping through with the debugger?

Comment: @Kyle, yes, index and others, ofcourse

Comment: @RowlandShaw, yes. I debugging it 2 days :) I cant find any solution...

Comment: Look in Fiddler2 to see what is initiating the request.

Comment: Localhost is reloaded. First localhost loading, then images loading and loacalhost reload again.

Comment: I think I found the solution. There is img tag in partial page like this: `<img src="~/@item.Yazar.KucukProfilResim" />` if image src null, it load localhost again.

Comment: I removes tilda (~) character, and it works expected.